# How to send mail smtp in local host by VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

I have used VB.net for my project, ticketing system, where you add new ticket it should be sending mail to some Emails I have defined in other class

but I have silly problem, which is sending mail through local host.

is there any suggestion from this source code, when I uploaded to specific domain it works, but for localhost not working with me which that  I don't receive any mail when I run my project

I want to send mail from localhost

```
Private Function SendConfirmationEmail(ByVal EmailAddress As String, ByVal Operation As String, ByVal CorreCode As String, ByVal CorrSubj As String, ByVal CutName As String, ByVal phone As String, ByVal CustomerEmail As String) As Boolean
    ''''''''''''''''''''''Getting Email Setting Information'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Try
        Dim FromMail As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("DefualtMail")(0).ToString()
        Dim PassMail As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("DefualtMailPass")(0).ToString
        Dim SenderName As String = "Customer Managment Team"
        Dim SMTPHost As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("SMTPHost")(0).ToString
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Sending Emails'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim Mail As New MailMessage
        Dim Body As String = ""
        Dim Subject As String = Operation
        Dim SendTo As String = EmailAddress
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''E-mail'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''    
        If SendTo <> vbNullString Then
            Mail.To.Clear()
            Mail.CC.Clear()
            Mail.Bcc.Clear()
            Mail.To.Add(SendTo)
            Mail.From = New MailAddress(FromMail, "Ticket Code   : " + CorreCode)
            Mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            Dim reader As StreamReader
            reader = New StreamReader(Server.MapPath("Index.html"))
            Body = reader.ReadToEnd
            Body = Body.Replace("MessageSubject", Operation)
            Body = Body.Replace("Description", "description  :  " + CorrSubj)
            Body = Body.Replace("customer_info", "Customer Name  :  " + CutName)
            Body = Body.Replace("phone_number", "Customer Phone  :  " + phone)
            Body = Body.Replace("email_address", "Customer address  :  " + CustomerEmail)
            ' Body = Body.Replace("PropertyTitle", "Ticket Code   :" + CorreCode + "   Ticket Description  :" + CorrSubj + " Customer info : " + CutName + " phone number : " + phone + " email_address : " + EmailAddress)
            Mail.Body = Body
            ' "<html dir='ltr'><body><h1>Confirmation</h1><br/> Please confirm you email at this link <br/> <a href='108.60.209.97/enmaa/ConfirmEmail.aspx/Enmaa0000" + ApproveId + "'>Confirm</a></body></html>"
            Mail.Subject = Subject
            '######################################## Sending The EMail########################################################
            Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient(SMTPHost)
            SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(FromMail, PassMail)
            SMTP.Host = SMTPHost
            SMTP.Port = 587 '587
            SMTP.EnableSsl = True
            SMTP.Send(Mail)
        End If
        Return True
```

Comment: Is the local configured to do so? Also please be more specific on ***not wotking***; is there errors, have you stepped through the code?

Comment: @Zaggler Helloo Zaggler, I mean (on not working), I don't receive any mail when I run my project on localhost

Comment: @MouazMazen Are you saying that you have an SMTP server set up on localhost, or are you saying that your program does not send email via a remote SMTP server? Exactly what error message do you get, if any?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hello Andrew, I was running my project at particular server it was sending mail, but when I run my project at localhost I it didn't send any mail. Also I didn't get any error message, my case is that possible to send mail from local host with these codes in above? 

from you comment, I noticed that could send mail without SMTP ? what are alternatives?

Comment: @MouazMazen You should use the same SMTP server used in the working configuration even when you are running from "localhost". If that is what you are doing then it is possible that the firewall or antivirus software on your computer is blocking the sending of emails from arbitrary programs.